# Android: Promote my other App when using Youtube Data API

Tags: android, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I am making an App consuming Youtube Data API. I have another app and i would like to promote that app in the app I am making. What is the best way to do that?

Is it ok to show a banner at the bottom of the Activity listing the videos or it would be fine if I show the Header of the list?

Or is there some other recommended way to do it?

Thanks in advance!